# Как одновременно обрабатывать запросы 2 и более аккаунтов?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот

При создании бота столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при отправке сообщений с двух разных аккаунтов ВК, бот работает последовательно, то есть всё равно, что если бы я писал боту с одного аккаунта. Допустим, если Пользователь 1 в меню дошёл до выбора проектов(в коде project1 и тд), а Пользователь 2 находится в меню выбора игры(в коде game1 и тд) и Пользователь 2 выбирает допустим game1, то он переходит сразу в меню выбора серверов(в коде server1 и тд), хотя по логике вещей должен был перейти в меню выбора проектов.
Как можно решить эту проблему?
Использую библиотеки: asyncio и aiovk

```
async def main():
session = TokenSession(access_token=TOKEN())
api = API(session)
longpoll = BotsLongPoll(session, mode=8, group_id=VK_GROUP_ID())

while True:
    try:
        data = await longpoll.wait()
        updates = data['updates']

        for event in updates:
            if event['type'] == 'message_new':
                payload = event['object']['message']['payload']
                responce = event['object']['message']['text'].lower
                dict_event = event['object']['message']

                if payload == '{"button":"1"}':
                    await api('messages.send',
                              peer_id=event['object']['message']['peer_id'],
                              message="game 1\n",
                              random_id=0,
                              keyboard=keyboardReturnMenu)

                elif (responce == '1') and (payload_event == '{"button":"1"}'): \
                    stage3_menu1 = 1
                    await api('messages.send',
                              peer_id=event['object']['message']['peer_id'],
                              message="project 1\n",
                              random_id=0,
                              keyboard=keyboardReturnMenu)

                elif (stage3_menu1 == 1) and (responce == '1'):
                    stage3_menu1 = 0
                    await api('messages.send',
                              peer_id=event['object']['message']['peer_id'],
                              message="server 1\nserver 2\nserver 3\n",
                              random_id=0,
                              keyboard=keyboardReturnMenu)


                if dict_event.get('payload') != None:
                    payload_event = event['object']['message']['payload']
                else:
                    payload_event = None

    except Exception as E:
        time.sleep(1)
        await session.close()
```

Comment: Вы храните 1 глобальное состояние, которое работает для всех пользователей. Необходимо, чтобы сервер запоминал, в каком состоянии находится **каждый** пользователь. В качестве идентификатора пользователя можно использовать `['object']['message']['peer_id']`.

Comment: Запоминать состояния бесед и идентификаторы бесед, а не пользователей. Извиняюсь.

Comment: До конца зарегистрировал учётку и теперь в собственном вопрос не могу добавлять комментарии, ибо нету 50 очков репутации, поэтому напишу тут) Надеюсь, не критично.
@МихаилМуругов Какой параметр отвечает за состояние бесед? Просто мне в голову приходит только conversation_message_id, это то?

Comment: @MESQ Создаёте его сами. Условно, создаёте словарик `states`, в котором ключами будут являться какие-то идентификаторы пользователей. В данном контексте, состояние - на какой "стадии" находится пользователь (выбор проекта, выбор сервера и т.д.). Затем для каждого пользователя запоминать, в каком состоянии он находится. Например, `states[user_id] = "Choosing project"` и т.д. Точно также можно будет смотреть, в каком состоянии находится какой-то пользователь. Не обязательно делать именно так, как я сказал, это просто как идея.

Answer (score -1):

Используйте класс `Thread` из пакета `threading`.

```
Thread(target=<название_функции_обработчика>,args=(<аргументы>,)).start()
```

Comment: Не является решением проблемы.

Comment: Мне подсказали, что я неправильно использую асинхронность и у меня всё равно код получается синхронным. В этом может заключаться проблема?

Comment: @user388561 вполне возможно